# What are the algebraic operations of the following vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I'm working on this exercise:

**Let $\{e_1,..., e_n\}$ be a basis for a complex vector space $X$. Find a basis for $X$ regarded as a real vector space. What is the dimension of $X$ in either case?**

My question is: What are (explicitly) the algebraic operations of the 'new' real vector space defined from that complex? I understand one of its basis is $\{e_1,..., e_n, ie_1,..., ie_n\}$ for $\{1, i\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{C}$; but I don't see what 'do' its operations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition on $X$ is the addition that you already add there. And the product of a real number $\lambda$ by a vector $x\in X$ is $\lambda x$, where you see $\lambda$ as a complex number. In other words, you restrict to the reals the multiplication by a complex scalar.

Comment: Then the dimension of a vector space resulting from restricting the field (to a proper subfield) is not necessarily less than the dimension of the original (finite-dimensional) space as we see when we restrict the set, considering a proper subspace. Is there some result that link the dimensions of both in some way (in the 'field-restriction' case)?

Comment: Yes. If $X$ is a $n$-dimensional complex vector space, then it is a $2n$-dimensional real vector space.

Comment: What can we say in the general (any field) case with respect to any of its sub-fields?

Comment: If $K$ is a subfield, if $L$ is a subfield of $K$, if $X$ is a $n$-dimensional $K$-vector space and if the dimension of $K$ as a $L$-vector space is $k$, then the dimension of $X$ as a $L$-vector space is $k\times n$.